# Lodash group by multiple keys

Tags: lodash

I have following object

```js
[{ Venue: 'NY',
    Title: 'NY Feast',
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Price : $49.99,
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' },
  { Venue: 'NY',
    Title: 'NY Flash',
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Price : $40.99,
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' },
  { Venue: 'BOSTON',
    Title: 'Never Too Late',
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Price : $9.99,
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' },
  { Venue: 'BOSTON',
    Title: 'The Reluctant Bride',
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Price : $19.99,
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' 
 }
]
```

Expected output after performing operation is

```js
[{ Venue: 'NY',
    Titles:  [{Title: 'NY Feast', Price: '49.99'}, {Title:'NY Flash', Price: '$40.99'}],
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' },
  { Venue: 'BOSTON',
    Titles: [{Title: 'Never Too Late', Price: '$9.99'}, {Title: 'The Reluctant Bride', Price: '$19.99'}] ,
    PromoDate: '5/1/18',
    EndDate: '5/1/18',
    Notes: '',
    'Image Assigned': '',
    'Image Ready': '',
    'Ad Scheduled': '' }
]
```

I am trying with Lodash groupby but it isn't working for me. I have to group by title, PromoDate and EndDate as those are unique field.

I will appreciate any help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single `Array.reduce` and without `lodash`:

```js
let data = [{ Venue: 'NY', Title: 'NY Feast', PromoDate: '5/1/18', EndDate: '5/1/18', Price: '$49.99', Notes: '', 'Image Assigned': '', 'Image Ready': '', 'Ad Scheduled': '' }, { Venue: 'NY', Title: 'NY Flash', PromoDate: '5/1/18', EndDate: '5/1/18', Price: '$40.99', Notes: '', 'Image Assigned': '', 'Image Ready': '', 'Ad Scheduled': '' }, { Venue: 'BOSTON', Title: 'Never Too Late', PromoDate: '5/1/18', EndDate: '5/1/18', Price: '$9.99', Notes: '', 'Image Assigned': '', 'Image Ready': '', 'Ad Scheduled': '' }, { Venue: 'BOSTON', Title: 'The Reluctant Bride', PromoDate: '5/1/18', EndDate: '5/1/18', Price: '$19.99', Notes: '', 'Image Assigned': '', 'Image Ready': '', 'Ad Scheduled': '' } ]

let result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  let key = `${c.Venue}-${c.PromoDate}-${c.EndDate}`
  let { Title, Price, ...other } = c
  r[key] = r[key] || { Titles: [], ...other }
  r[key].Titles.push({ Title, Price })
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The idea is to group on the composite key and then just reduce to the properties you need.

Comment: Is there a way to return array instead of object so i can map through it ?

Comment: @jvm can you update the desired output so I can see what you mean if you do not mind? I am currently returning an array of objects ...